# Sorting the files in a directory by the last delimited substring while displaying the original file name

Tags: shell, sorting, unix

I have a directory that contains files ending in a timestamp. I would like to iterate through the files in this directory order by that timestamp in the name. I am doing this in a shell script in Unix.

```
filename1_20230517_065806.txt
filename2_20230517_055806.txt
filename_3_20230517_125806.txt
file_name_4_20230517_063806.txt
```

I need this to be processed in the following order

```
filename2_20230517_055806.txt
file_name_4_20230517_063806.txt
filename1_20230517_065806.txt
filename_3_20230517_125806.txt
```

The order should only be looking at the time section of the file name. I was hoping to do something like this, but since the filed names can have any number of underscores I'm having difficulties.

```
for i in $(ls *.txt | sort -t'_' -k3)
do...
```

Is there a way to have sort look at the last delimited index and sort by that?

Comment: Is file creation time is the same order as the timestamp from file names?

Comment: if you're using `-t_` to sort by keys, you need to ensure each filename is formatted with the same number of `_` chars, while your sample filenames are NOT (-; Is that a typo, or does it really reflect the data you have to use? Good luck.

Comment: @shellter, that is exactly the issue I have. The filed name might have a variable number of underscores. We then tack on the date and time of the file's creation at the end. We have these files fed to us so they are all created at the same time. I can't go by the ctime. The only thing I have to go by is the last six chars in the file name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use "rev" to reverse the elements and than sort with the first two elements:

```
#!/bin/bash

filenames="filename1_20230517_065806.txt filename2_20230517_055806.txt filename_3_20230517_125806.txt file_name_4_20230517_063806.txt"

# Convert the filenames string into an array
IFS=' ' read -r -a files_array <<< "$filenames"

# Sort the array based on the timestamp with reversed elements
sorted_array=($(for file in "${files_array[@]}"; do
  timestamp=$(echo "$file" | rev | cut -d_ -f1,2 | rev)
  echo "$timestamp $file"
done | sort | cut -d' ' -f2))

for file in "${sorted_array[@]}"; do
  echo "$file"
done
```

The output looks like expected:

```
filename2_20230517_055806.txt
file_name_4_20230517_063806.txt
filename1_20230517_065806.txt
filename_3_20230517_125806.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you’re going to need the help of awk for this, using the “trick” of temporarily augmenting the data by prefixing each line with the desired sort key. I added in the date ($(NF-1)) to the sort key below as well.

`for i in $(ls *.txt | awk -F_ ‘{print $(NF-1) $NF “\t” $0}’ | sort | cut -f 2-) do...`

Answer (score 1):

```
$ find . -type f -name "*.txt"|awk -F_ '{a[$NF]=$0} END{n=asorti(a,b); for(i=1; i<=n; i++) print a[b[i]]}'
./filename2_20230517_055806.txt
./file_name_4_20230517_063806.txt
./filename1_20230517_065806.txt
./filename_3_20230517_125806.txt
```